# How to create a column of mysql using another column

Tags: mysql

| id | name | updated_at | desc_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bananas | 2021-12-06 09:58:59 | 2 |
| 2 | Melons | 2022-01-10 10:08:57 | 1 |
| 3 | Pies | 2019-11-07 11:20:48 | 3 |

I need to create the column desc_id that takes informations from updated_at and gives back ids in descending order from the oldes to the newest .

I have so little information of mysql that i don't know where to start.

Comment: It's not a good idea to create a column in the table to store this since it may then be incorrect when you insert a new row..

Comment: i will add a cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here to generate the `desc_id` sequence:

```sql
SELECT id, name, updated_at,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY updated_at DESC) desc_id
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

The above assumes you are using MySQL 8+.  For earlier versions of MySQL, we can try:

```sql
SELECT id, name, updated_at,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.updated_at >= t1.updated_at) desc_id
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: it doesn't save it in the table, when i refresh the page desc_id isn't there

Comment: @Tammapao you should not save this information in the table. Create a view out of the select statement if you want to have a similar experience to a table.